# How to shorten this JQuery Code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript/jQuery. Is there a way to make this code shorter?

```
else if (players == 6) {
    $('#box1').addClass("col-md-4");
    $('#box1').removeClass("col-md-6");
    $('#box2').addClass("col-md-4");
    $('#box2').removeClass("col-md-6");
    $('#box3').addClass("col-md-4");
    $('#box3').removeClass("col-md-6");
    $('#box4').addClass("col-md-4");
    $('#box4').removeClass("col-md-6");
    $('#box4').removeClass("col-md-offset-4");
    $('#box5').addClass("col-md-4");
    $('#box5').removeClass("col-md-6");
    $('#box6').addClass("col-md-4");
    $('#box6').removeClass("col-md-6");
    $('#box1').show();
    $('#box2').show();
    $('#box3').show();
    $('#box4').show();
    $('#box5').show();
    $('#box6').show();
}
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim the pastebin link.

Comment: Please add your full code in your question. You can add a link as a reference.

Comment: Please read the comment by T.K. Crowder

Comment: As stated above, please *always* include your code in the question. I've edited it for you in this case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Sorry, didn't know this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [combine the selectors](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/) and apply each method with chaining.

```
else if (players == 6) {
   $('#box1,#box2,#box3,#box4,#box5,#box6')
        .addClass("col-md-4")
        .removeClass("col-md-6")
        .show();
}
```

---

Or use [attribute starts with the selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/).

```
else if (players == 6) {
   $('[id^="box"]')
        .addClass("col-md-4")
        .removeClass("col-md-6")
        .show();
}
```

---

Or use a common class for elements and select based on that.

```
else if (players == 6) {
   $('.box')
        .addClass("col-md-4")
        .removeClass("col-md-6")
        .show();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

when you could give all your boxes a class like .box you could do this (preferred)

```
$('.box').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6").show();
```

or you could do this

```
$('#box1, #box2, #box3').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6").show();
```

in stead of:

```
$('#box1').addClass("col-md-4");
$('#box1').removeClass("col-md-6");
$('#box2').addClass("col-md-4");
$('#box2').removeClass("col-md-6");
$('#box3').addClass("col-md-4");
$('#box3').removeClass("col-md-6");
$('#box4').addClass("col-md-4");
$('#box4').removeClass("col-md-6");
$('#box4').removeClass("col-md-offset-4");
$('#box5').addClass("col-md-4");
$('#box5').removeClass("col-md-6");
$('#box6').addClass("col-md-4");
$('#box6').removeClass("col-md-6");
$('#box1').show();
$('#box2').show();
$('#box3').show();
$('#box4').show();
$('#box5').show();
$('#box6').show();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

```
else if (players == 6) {
   $('[id^="box"]').removeClass("col-md-6").addClass("col-md-4").show();
}
```

or you can use attribute like

```
else if (players == 6) {
   $('[data-box="true"]').removeClass("col-md-6").addClass("col-md-4").show();
}
```

All those elements should have data-box="true" attribute.

Also, you could use some dummy class with your slectors and do the following:

```
else if (players == 6) {
   $('.dummy').removeClass("col-md-6").addClass("col-md-4").show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the way to shorten your links. because you have

**.removeClass("col-md-offset-4")**

```
if (players === 6) {
     $('#box1').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6").show();
     $('#box2').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6").show();
     $('#box3').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6").show();
     $('#box4').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6 col-md-offset-4").show();
     $('#box5').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6").show();
     $('#box6').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6").show();
    }
```

**OR**

```
if (players === 6) {
    $('#box1,#box2,#box3,#box5,#box6').addClass("col-md-4").removeClass("col-md-6").show();
    $('#box4').addClass("col-md-4")removeClass("col-md-6 col-md-offset-4").show();
    }
```